# Mind maps vs spreadsheets

Tags: manual-testing, documentation

We've been using Google docs spreadsheets to keep test scenarios for manual testing of our applications for quite a long time.

Recently, we've started to use *mind maps* as well, mapping the functionality of an application in different nodes and even adding some tests and checks attached to nodes.

Is it a good idea to replace spreadsheet based test scenarios (defined in a classical table-like manner) with mind maps completely? Or, should we keep both of the formats and use a mind map more as a visualizer of the functionality of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal suggestion is:

- Keep both, mind map by nature is a visual tool; it is good to demonstrate relationship among test ideas but you can not apply formulas as easily as you can with Google Docs; you can not sort in a desc order as easily as you can with Google Docs etc.

When you talk about Mind Map, are you referring to the Mind map or mind mapping tool in general? There is a mind mapping application you can take a look at, [MindMeister](https://support.mindmeister.com/hc/en-us)

Comment: I was referring to the Mind Map concept in general. We are using MindJet, but I'll definitely check out MindMeister. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think no one can answer that better than you. Are your tests steps still as understandable to new comments as in spreadsheets? Are those easily reproducible by them? Does it take more time to write a test or edit a test set? What do you gain and lose by moving there? If nothing is changed in speed and complications then you should not move to something else. If you gain a better understandable tests which are easier to write and read - definitely improve your flow. There are different products and tests so some would prefer one approach over another.